# Why is my painted plywood wall flaky and thin-looking?

Tags: paint, plywood

I painted my workshop made with plywood with white emulsion paint but the result isn’t what I was expecting The paint did not stick to the wood properly which resulted in a flaky and patchy white wooden wall.

The paint I used was new and thoroughly mixed before applying; the plywood surface was dry before applying the paint as well.

What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: You used a plain water-based paint on a wood surface.  You should use a sealer, an oil-based paint, or a paint that is "certified" as being appropriate for wood.

Comment: Did you prime it ?

Comment: It can be saved by second or 3d coat

Comment: Will a coat of oil based primer applied now over the emulsion (aka latex in the US) harden the emulsion? Or does one have to scrape and sand off the emulsion before applying primer? Water based primer does not work on wood because it raises the grain. Oil based primer does not do that.

Comment: @JimStewart  I have to disagree to a small degree, yes, water based primer (and paint) does raise the grain, but a very light sanding will knock that down and ready it for paint, WATER BASED AT THIS POINT, DON'T USE OIL BASED!  The first coat of paint may also very slightly raise the grain if places that might have been sanded thru the primer.  A VERY LIGHT sanding would knock that down and the 2nd coat should be perfect.  Of course  be sure to blow off or wipe down any and all sanding dust or you'll be doing this for a long time!

Comment: When finishing plywood, I normally sand lightly to knock down imperfections as well as any leftovers (chemicals) from the manufacturing process.  I have had decent luck with water based finishes on plywood, but yeah, it takes 2 coats at least:  First one to seal and raise the grain, then after sanding and wiping it down, the 2nd coat to give it a decent finish.   I hardly ever bother with sealer, I just throw the first coat on, sand it and then the second coat.   In your (the OP) case, I agree with Ruskes that it can be saved, IF you lightly sand it between coats.

Comment: Mostly looks like a first coat that might need 3 coats to look decent, somewhat unevenly applied which doesn't help the look. Despite the wording of the question claiming "flaky" I don't see anything peeling. Looks like roller applied without the roller being evenly loaded. Not using a roller tray, or using a roller tray wrong, perhaps? Disagree with the "must use oil paint" opinion strongly, from experience.

Comment: I'd agree that there was a fair amount of poor technique involved here. I'd suggest watching several YouTube videos on how to paint with a roller. While there is some junk info on YT, if you watch several (especially ones from paint manufacturers or well known & respected home improvement shows), you'll see what's done in common in them and pick up correct tips on _how_ to paint with a roller. This will help your 2nd coat go on better and more evenly, and by the time the 3rd coat goes on, this will be but a distant memory.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I have successfully used water-based wood primer (and even emulsion) under oil-based gloss on wood.  It's OK, very different to the other way round.  Of course it's extra important to make sure the water-based coat is fully dry before applying the oil-based.

Comment: I don't see any signs of flaking, only patchiness and drips.  A first coat is likely to be patchy, and the drips might have been caused by trying to apply too much paint to the roller and wall in one go

Comment: @ChrisH  Glad you had decent luck on that.  To me finishing wood is a black art involving incantations a witches brews.   So once I find something that works, I stick with it.  I now like Pre-cat lacquer (NOT DEFT lacquer), the pre-cat is very durable, dries very quickly and stands up to water (like from condensation on a drinking glass with ice), It's tough stuff and I usually only need to do 2 coats.  But it's nasty to shoot, I do it outside and wear a full blown charcoal respirator, but I've still probably taken a few years off my life!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson my last wood project was a toy wagon made with my daughter.  A late change of plans and some free leftover gloss meant it was going on top of emulsion - which I'd used because I'd run out of water-based wood primer and the shops had shut.  It's robust enough to get knocked around.

Comment: I appreciate getting corrected on my claim that water based paints should never be used directly on raw wood. I had had disappointing results with water based stain on fine solid oak interior doors. The final finish was tung oil, but the grain is permanently raised. We just live with it, but when we finally sell the house (to go into assisted living) I'm sure the discerning buyer will shake his head. I suppose someone who knows how to sand could salvage these solid oak doors.

Comment: How large is this workshop? Are there any local fire code guidelines or requirements prescribing the use of fire resistant wall materials? Plywood especially with certain finishes might be in violation. Is this in a fully detached house? Where is this located--what country and county?

Comment: @JimStewart those are [BS1363 sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types) used in the UK, Ireland and some commonwealth countries, etc. I don't believe there's such a regulation in the UK in general, though in some specific cases there are (the ceilings of integral garages is one I've come up against).  At the other end of the scale outbuilding workshops (which this presumably isn't) are often mainly wood.

Answer (score 2):

Emulsion works pretty well on wood products, and isn't that different from the widely sold water-based wood primers.   It does tend to raise the grain on the first coat, but that will sand down really easily with fine sandpaper.  In the worst cases or if you sand too much, you may raise the grain a little on a 2nd coat too.  Just sand again and recoat

Emulsion on wood normally needs 3 coats total, the first acting as a primer.  It sticks really well if the wood wasn't greasy or dusty to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really tempted to give it a coat of thinned PVA glue, then another coat or two of emulsion after it's had good time to dry.

Anything oil-based now is not going to do the job it would have on bare wood. PVA will soak through the existing coat well enough to bond & prep the surface.

PVA is cheap as chips, from any hardware store, supermarket decorating section, B&Q, Asda, Wilko's etc. Don't bother with a premium manufacturer you've heard of, it's all the same stuff.
e.g [Diall from B&Q](https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-white-multi-purpose-pva-adhesive-500ml/5059340110776_BQ.prd)
Read the instructions for how much to thin it down.

> Product information
>
> Multipurpose PVA adhesive is a bonding agent, adhesive and sealer. Suitable for a variety of jobs including as a cement and plaster admixture. Will bond to most common building and DIY materials, except PVC and rubber. Ideal for priming unsound surfaces prior to plastering or painting as an adhesive on wood, cork, textiles and most applications where at least one surface is porous. For general dust sealing on flaking paintwork and walls etc. And as an admixture for cement, mortar, screeds and renders

<sup>BTW, paint over the cables - but not the socket, of course. It will look better than trying to work around them & failing. Best would be to take the socket off until you're done. Turn the breaker off & just let it hang till you're finished.

And use a brush at the edges & corners, don't try to get the roller to squeeze in.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For plywood projects, water-based acrylic-latex paints are generally the easiest to work with. Epoxy paints also offer great durability. Opt for high-quality paint and apply with a quality brush for the best possible results. Wet the brush before painting, and apply in the direction of the top grain.